# Gremlin - Vertex and Edge Upsert in 1 traversal

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, upsert, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a Vertex upsert working and an Edge upsert working in 2 separate traversals.  Is it possible to combine the 2 into 1 traversal?  I have attempted but am receiving errors.

a = self.g.V().has('account', 'id', 'account-111111111').fold().coalesce(**.unfold(),**.addV('account').property(T.id, 'account-111111111')).has('customer', 'id', 'cust-111111111').as_('v').V().has('account', 'id', 'account-111111111').coalesce(**.inE('owns').where(**.outV().as_('v')),**.addE('owns').from_(**.V('customer', 'id', 'cust-111111111')))

a.next()

Works:

Vertex Upsert:

a = g.V().has('account', 'id', 'account-111111111').fold().coalesce(**.unfold(),**.addV('account').property(T.id, 'account-111111111'))
a.next()

Edge Upsert:

a = g.V().has('customer', 'id', 'cust-111111111').as_('v').V().has('account', 'id', 'account-111111111). \
                coalesce(**.inE('owns').where(**.outV().as_('v')),**.addE('owns').from_(**.V('customer', 'id', 'cust-111111111])))

a.next()

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please edit the question to include the error messages that you are seeing?

Comment: Also note that 'id' is not the same as T.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After studying it for a while, there are quite a few things in your example that will not work.

First of all if you know the ID of a vertex or an edge there is really no need to check the label or any other property.

Secondly T.id is an ID. The value 'id' would be a property called 'id'.

From your question it was a bit hard to piece together what you are wanting to do but here is a first go at what I think you intended. If this is not in fact what you wanted please edit the question to make it more clear. Anyway, I hope this helps

```
g.V('account-111111111').
  fold().
  coalesce(__.unfold(),
           __.addV('account').property(T.id, 'account-111111111')).
  coalesce(__.in('owns').hasId('cust-111111111')),
           __.addE('owns').from_(__.V('cust-111111111'))
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin.  In the first step account-11111111 vertex may not exist yet so I must check and add it if it does not exist.  So in step 1 I need to make sure that the vertex exists, and add it if not, and in the second step create or update the edge between the customer vertex and the account vertex.

Comment: I will be looping through a list passing variables in for the account and. customer.  I have. hardcoded the values for this example.  I need to create a new vertex or update it if it exists.  Then create or update the edge between the account and customer vertex.  I am not sure if this can be done in one traversal.

Comment: Were you able to try the example I used in my answer. It does what you describe in your first comment doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had to edit your code a bit but it definitely got me there.   g.V('account-111111111').fold().coalesce(__.unfold(),__.addV('account').property(T.id, 'account-111111111')).coalesce(__.inE('owns').where(__.outV().hasId('cust-111111111'))),__.addE('owns').from_(__.V('cust-111111111'))

Comment: still having an issue updating an existing edge

Comment: edge is updating my mistake